# Aliases and tmux

Tags: command-line, terminal, tmux

Aliases defined in `.bash_aliases` and `.bashrc` don't work in `tmux`.

Can this be changed in some configuration, so the aliases work under `tmux`?

Comment: Are you sure problem is in `tmux`? I use tmux about year and haven't seen any problems with aliases. Try to add `set -x` at the begin of your `.bashrc` and run in `tmux` command `source ~/.bashrc` . May be you'll find any errors and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tmux` launches a login shell by default, so `~/.bashrc` will not be executed (which then subsequently sources `~/.bash_aliases`. You need to source `~/.bashrc` from your `~/.bash_profile`. See the `INVOCATION` section of `man bash`.

Answer (score 22):

*([Chris Down's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38402/aliases-and-tmux/38407#38407) has the right explanation but not a good workaround)*

Your problem stems from a combination of a bash design bug and a tmux design bug.

By default, tmux starts a login shell in every window. This doesn't make any sense: if you've set tmux as your login shell, you need to set the `default-command` option to something other than tmux; and if you haven't set tmux as your login shell, you need to set the `default-command` option to avoid starting a login shell inside tmux. So put the following in your `~/.tmux.conf` to tell tmux to start an ordinary shell:

```
set-option -g default-command $SHELL
```

Then your `.bashrc` will be read. There is another issue with bash, which doesn't matter here if you configure tmux as recommended above, but which will surface again if you log in in text mode (on a text console, or over SSH). Bash reads `~/.bash_profile` in login shells, and `~/.bashrc` in interactive shells but only if they are not login shells. To read `~/.bashrc` also in login shells if they're interactive, add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

Comment: +!  It took that last part to get my aliases and PS1 prompt fixed, but it did!